# List of Alfresco activity types

Tags: android-activity, alfresco

When posting an Activity with the Alfresco javascript
postActivity(activityType, siteId, appTool, jsonActivityData)

function, 
what are the possible activityType entries?
what are the possible appTool entries?

Actually, I would like to be able to add a new entry with custom text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The values for activityType and appTool are completely up to the developer to choose. It can be virtually anything (within the bounds of the parameter type). This allows you to define any type of custom events by just choosing you own activityType. The appTool should be considered a coarser grained grouping for activityTypes that define the context. E.g. an out-of-the-box appTool is the "documentLibrary" which groups all kinds of activityTypes that originate from the Alfresco Share Document Library functionalities, like the activityType "org.alfresco.documentlibrary.file-added".

The activityType can also be used to differentiate between FreeMarker template files that transform an activity post into an activity feed entry. The activityType is used as a package and file name in this case, so there exists a FreeMarker template file in the /alfresco/templates/activities/org/alfresco/documentlibrary location called file-added.atomentry.ftl that is used to generate an Atom feed entry from an activity post using the activityType "org.alfresco.documentlibrary.file-added".
Most of the time though, JSON format is used and what you put into the activity post is what you get out of the feed entry.